# export query to excel and have a progress bar for it

Tags: php

Good day

I am currently struggling with regards to outputting a progress bar while my query is being exported to an excel file. The excel file tries to display the progress bar with the sheet instead of it being displayed on the web browser. I tried using the exit method but the code that contains the progress bar which is underneath is not read instead.

Here is the code:

```
<?php connect_local_host();?>
<html lang="en">
this is for the progress bar
<body>

this is for the progress bar

<!-- Progress bar holder -->
<div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
<!-- Progress information -->
<div id="information" style="width"></div>

this code here is for exporting the query
<?php

function connect_local_host()
{

$time_start = microtime(true);

$mysqlserver = "localhost";         
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "Profusion";

$link = mysql_connect( "$mysqlserver", $user, $pass );
if ( ! $link )
die( "Couldn't connect to MySQL" );
//print "Successfully connected to server<P>";

mysql_select_db( $db )
or die ( "Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error() );
//print "Successfully selected database \"$db\"<P>"; 

$query = "SELECT uniqueid,cdr_id from source_cdr";
$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
$header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
$line = '';

foreach( $row as $value )
{                                            
if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
{
    $value = "\t";
}
else
{
    $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
    $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
}

$line .= $value;
}
$data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );
if ( $data == "" )
{
$data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=audit_data.xls");

header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Expires: 0");

print "$header\n$data";

//exit();

//}

// this is for the total time taken to execute the export code
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
$t_t=$time/$fields;
$total = $t_tstrong text;
// Loop through process

for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)
{
// Calculate the percentage
$percent = floatval($i/$total * 100)."%";/

echo round($percent,0); 

// Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
echo '<script language="javascript">

document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-      color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
</script>';

// This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

// Send output to browser immediately
flush();

// Sleep one second so we can see the delay
sleep(1);
}

// Tell user that the process is completed
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process   completed"   </script>';

echo '<br/>';
echo  "Total time taken :"." ".round($time,6) . " s";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't people use fputcsv() when writing csv files?

Comment: this was actually exported to an excel file instead Mark, the export code works perfectly I am actually struggling to exit from the export code and start reading the progress bar code so that the progress bar can be displayed on the web browser instead of the excel worksheet.

Comment: @MarkBaker because it's too easy.  OP: You're not doing anything in your code that would actually update the progress bar in real time. You'd need to query the server for status on the process via JS so that you can update your bar.

Comment: @user1002713 it's not an excel file at all, you can't call a file *.xls and expect it to magical change format. you are creating a *.csv file, so why not call it that. if you want to create a real excel file take a look at http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: okay I just noticed that most examples related to my question display real time progress bars using forms now is it possible to get a real time progress bar of data sent to a mysql database?